# Adam Bashforth predictor corrector method second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I'm trying to numerical solve a 2nd order differential equation, I know the usual way of doing this is using Runge-Kutta's Method. But then I wonder if I could do it with Adam-Bashford and Adam-Bashford predictor-corrector. To my surprise, although theoretically, it is possible to do so, I didn't end up finding any implementation nor straight forward formula, so I wrote this:

```
# AB
Y[i + 1] = Y[i] + h*(55.0 * U[i] - 59.0 * U[i-1] + 37.0 * U[i-2] - 9.0 * U[i-3])/24.0
U[i + 1] = U[i] + h*(55.0 * dudx(X[i],Y[i],U[i]) - 59.0 * dudx(X[i-1],Y[i-1],U[i-1]) + 37.0 * dudx(X[i-2],Y[i-2],U[i-2]) - 9.0 * dudx(X[i-3],Y[i-3],U[i-1]))/24.0
#AB predictor-corrector
Y[i + 1] = Y[i] + h*(55.0 * U[i] - 59.0 * U[i-1] + 37.0 * U[i-2] - 9.0 * U[i-3])/24.0
U[i + 1] = U[i] + h*(55.0 * dudx(X[i],Y[i],U[i]) - 59.0 * dudx(X[i-1],Y[i-1], U[i-1]) + 37.0 * dudx(X[i-2],Y[i-2], U[i-2]) - 9.0 * dudx(X[i-3],Y[i-3],U[i-3]))/24.0
            
            
Y[i + 1] = Y[i] + h*(9.0 * U[i+1] + 19.0 * U[i] - 5.0 * U[i-1] + U[i-2])/24.0
U[i + 1] = U[i] + h*(9.0 * dudx(X[i+1], Y[i + 1], U[i+1]) + 19.0 * dudx(X[i],Y[i], U[i]) - 5.0 * dudx(X[i-1],Y[i-1], U[i-1]) + dudx(X[i-2],Y[i-2], U[i-2]))/24.0
```

where $u=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $dudx=\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$. I believed that this would result in a better estimate of the solution. But it seems AB is less accurate than rk4 and ABP-C is just a little better than rk4, Have I done something wrong? If not, Is there any way that someone can explain why this happens?

This is the result I got for the equation:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y''+y'-6y=0\\
y(0)=1, y'(0)=2 
\end{array}\right. 
$$
where $y(x)=e^{2x}$ with this different methods:
[image]

Comment: Does [this](/questions/3446434) answer your question?

Comment: Repeat the experiment with 1/2 or 1/10 the step size, but displaying the same points. You should get 1 or 4 more equal digits in the tables. // With a Lipschitz constant of $3$ and a step size of $0.1$, you can expect about 2 digits accuracy in a 4th order method. Your tables show that in RK4 and AM4, and, at least some of the way, also in AB4.

Comment: @user10354138 this explanation was what I expected to happen but even with very small step sizes, rk4 performed better than AB4 and AM4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one error and one non-standard feature in your formulas, and thus apparently also in your computations. In the AB4 formula for the `Y` component, the last index should be `i-3` as the ones directly before it, not `i-1`. In the repetition as predictor for AM4 you have that correct. In the corrector you are using the freshly computed value for `Y[i+1]` in the computation of `U[i+1]`. This will produce a difference to vector-based standard implementations. This is basically the difference between a Gauß-Seidel scheme and a Jacobi scheme. If one were to continue the corrector iteration until numerical convergence, there should be no differences above floating point noise.

To check if you implemented the method correctly, you can compare the errors when dividing the step size by `N=2,4,8` etc. You should observe a reduction in error by a factor $16$ in each step. For a more visual confirmation, divide the step size by `N=10, 100`, etc. Then the number of correct digits should increase by 4 in each step. I computed such tables below, they show that clearly in the columns for `N=10`. It should be true in general that the columns have about 2, 6 and 10 correct digits after the dot, respectively, RK4 and AM4 partially a little more, AB4 a little less.

#### Runge-Kutta 4

| x | N=1 | N=10 | N=100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] |
| 0.1 | [ 1.221400000000, 2.442800000000] | [ 1.221402757840, 2.442805515680] | [ 1.221402758160, 2.442805516320] |
| 0.2 | [ 1.491817960000, 2.983635920000] | [ 1.491824696859, 2.983649393718] | [ 1.491824697641, 2.983649395282] |
| 0.3 | [ 1.822106456344, 3.644212912688] | [ 1.822118798957, 3.644237597914] | [ 1.822118800390, 3.644237600781] |
| 0.4 | [ 2.225520825779, 4.451041651557] | [ 2.225540926158, 4.451081852316] | [ 2.225540928492, 4.451081856984] |
| 0.5 | [ 2.718251136606, 5.436502273212] | [ 2.718281824895, 5.436563649789] | [ 2.718281828459, 5.436563656917] |
| 0.6 | [ 3.320071938250, 6.640143876501] | [ 3.320116917512, 6.640233835024] | [ 3.320116922736, 6.640233845472] |
| 0.7 | [ 4.055135865379, 8.110271730758] | [ 4.055199959400, 8.110399918800] | [ 4.055199966844, 8.110399933688] |
| 0.8 | [ 4.952942945974, 9.905885891948] | [ 4.953032414003, 9.906064828007] | [ 4.953032424394, 9.906064848788] |
| 0.9 | [ 6.049524514213, 12.099049028426] | [ 6.049647450134, 12.099294900267] | [ 6.049647464411, 12.099294928823] |
| 1.0 | [ 7.388889241659, 14.777778483319] | [ 7.389056079552, 14.778112159104] | [ 7.389056098929, 14.778112197857] |

#### Adams-Bashford 4

| x | N=1 | N=10 | N=100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] |
| 0.1 | [ 1.221400000000, 2.442800000000] | [ 1.221402748820, 2.442805497640] | [ 1.221402758159, 2.442805516318] |
| 0.2 | [ 1.491817960000, 2.983635920000] | [ 1.491824670099, 2.983649340199] | [ 1.491824697638, 2.983649395276] |
| 0.3 | [ 1.822106456344, 3.644212912688] | [ 1.822118747045, 3.644237494090] | [ 1.822118800384, 3.644237600769] |
| 0.4 | [ 2.225359751835, 4.450719503670] | [ 2.225540839268, 4.451081678535] | [ 2.225540928483, 4.451081856965] |
| 0.5 | [ 2.717819501390, 5.435639002780] | [ 2.718281690082, 5.436563380165] | [ 2.718281828444, 5.436563656888] |
| 0.6 | [ 3.319281371915, 6.638562743829] | [ 3.320116717817, 6.640233435634] | [ 3.320116922715, 6.640233845429] |
| 0.7 | [ 4.053852018449, 8.107704036897] | [ 4.055199672699, 8.110399345399] | [ 4.055199966813, 8.110399933626] |
| 0.8 | [ 4.950979883921, 9.901959767841] | [ 4.953032011560, 9.906064023120] | [ 4.953032424351, 9.906064848702] |
| 0.9 | [ 6.046643715383, 12.093287430766] | [ 6.049646894750, 12.099293789499] | [ 6.049647464353, 12.099294928705] |
| 1.0 | [ 7.384781911467, 14.769563822935] | [ 7.389055323232, 14.778110646464] | [ 7.389056098849, 14.778112197697] |

#### Adams-Moulton 4-1

| x | N=1 | N=10 | N=100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] | [ 1.000000000000, 2.000000000000] |
| 0.1 | [ 1.221400000000, 2.442800000000] | [ 1.221402758700, 2.442805517401] | [ 1.221402758160, 2.442805516321] |
| 0.2 | [ 1.491817960000, 2.983635920000] | [ 1.491824699412, 2.983649398824] | [ 1.491824697642, 2.983649395283] |
| 0.3 | [ 1.822106456344, 3.644212912688] | [ 1.822118803910, 3.644237607820] | [ 1.822118800391, 3.644237600782] |
| 0.4 | [ 2.225527878319, 4.451055756639] | [ 2.225540934448, 4.451081868896] | [ 2.225540928493, 4.451081856986] |
| 0.5 | [ 2.718268691144, 5.436537382288] | [ 2.718281837757, 5.436563675514] | [ 2.718281828460, 5.436563656920] |
| 0.6 | [ 3.320104159474, 6.640208318947] | [ 3.320116936565, 6.640233873130] | [ 3.320116922738, 6.640233845476] |
| 0.7 | [ 4.055188406071, 8.110376812142] | [ 4.055199986754, 8.110399973508] | [ 4.055199966847, 8.110399933694] |
| 0.8 | [ 4.953023229681, 9.906046459362] | [ 4.953032452400, 9.906064904800] | [ 4.953032424398, 9.906064848797] |
| 0.9 | [ 6.049642249362, 12.099284498725] | [ 6.049647503123, 12.099295006245] | [ 6.049647464417, 12.099294928835] |
| 1.0 | [ 7.389057076415, 14.778114152830] | [ 7.389056151712, 14.778112303424] | [ 7.389056098937, 14.778112197874] |

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, It seems that I have missed an 'i-3'. but the comparison is still the same meaning RK4>AM4>AB4 but for 1st order ODEs this is not the case, meaning AM4>AB4>RK4. this might not be true all the time but mostly we can expect this result or I believe so. So why isn't this holding for 2nd order ODEs?

Comment: The multi-step methods can only be as good as the starter sequence, so if you use RK4 for the starter, you can not get much better in the following iterations. In general there should be examples for both, AM4>RK4 especially in stiff problems with a sufficient number of corrector steps. I'm not sure what quality would make RK4 decidedly better than AM4, especially if you take multiple corrector iterations so that the count of function evaluations is the same.

Comment: I assumed that quality is having a lesser local error at steps meaning they have less error in the points they estimate, generally what I've seen in 1st order ODE is that AM4 shows less local error but of course local error is dependent on convergence speed. So what I mean to say is I believed that AM4 converges faster than RK4 for 2nd order ODE

Comment: Taking the test problem $y''(x)=F(x,y)+p''(x)-F(x,p(x))$ where $p(x)=\sin x$ with $y=p$ as exact solution, and $F(x,y)=-k·\sin y$ over $x\in[0,10]$, I get in general that RK4 has an error of about $0.1·h^4$ while the error of AB4 is about 8 times or more of that. For $k=1$ RK4 has $0.04·h^4$ while AM4 has $0.1·h^4$, for larger $k=4$ to $k=8$ and thus a slightly stiff equation this reverses, RK4 now has errors in the range $0.15·h^4$ while AM4 reduces to $0.05·h^4$